# Can I move the entire object?

Tags: swift, xcode, sprite-kit, swift4

I created objects with multidimensional array.

The last piece is moving when I try to move the resulting object.How can I move the formed shape entirely?

[image]

[image]

```
override func touchesMoved(_ touches: Set<UITouch>, with event: UIEvent?) {
    for touch: AnyObject in touches{

            let location = touch.location(in: self)
            square.position.x = location.x
            square.position.y = location.y
    }
}
```

Move Code:

I print them on the screen with the code below:

```
for row in 0..<t.bitmap.count {
        for col in 0..<t.bitmap[row].count {
            if t.bitmap[row][col] > 0 {
                let block = t.bitmap[row][col]

                square = SKSpriteNode(color: colors[block], size: CGSize(width: blockSize, height: blockSize))
                square.anchorPoint = CGPoint(x: 1.0, y: 0)
                square.position = CGPoint(x: col * Int(blockSize) + col, y: -row * Int(blockSize) + -row)
                square.position.x += location.x
                square.position.y += location.y
                self.addChild(square)

            }
        }
    }
```

Comment: don't use external hosting for images. Embed your images into your question instead. that way if the external site goes down or away your question is still relevant. also ask yourself if it is necessary to include the phone mockup in your images or that is just wasted space

Answer (score 0):

It is unclear what you are actually asking, the large images and missing code don't help. However it appears that you move a single block with:

```
square.position.x = location.x
square.position.y = location.y
```

And you wish to move all blocks by the same relative amount. You could probably achieve that by instead of the above two lines first calculating the relative amount in each direction:

```
let deltaX = location.x - square.position.x
let deltaY = location.y - square.position.y
```

And then calling a function to move all the blocks:

```
 moveAllBlocks(deltaX, deltaY)
```

This routine needs to iterate over all the blocks updating their `position` by adding the deltas.

HTH

---

**Addendum**

In response to comment

> I am bad speak english, sorry. example did not solve the problem. Yes, I want to move all the blocks.

Let's try with some example values to see if that helps, this will all be pseudo-code - you need to understand the algorithm and then implement in your code.

Assume you have an 8x8 grid and a number of tiles each of which as a location *(row, col)*. We will consider one tile which is currently at *(2, 3)*.

The touch event tells you to move this tile to, say, *(5, 1)*. You are currently achieving the move by *assigning* to the tiles location:

```
tile.location = (5, 1)
```

and are then faced with the problem of where to move the other tiles so they stay in the same *relative* position to the tile you have moved.

The solution is to first figure out the *relative* distance to move the first tile, rather than just assign its new absolute location, we do this by taking the difference between the new and old locations:

```
delta = newLocation - tile.location
      = (2, 3) - (5, 1)
      = (3, -2)
```

Now you have the relative amount, *(3, -2)*, to move the tile by you can move *all* the tiles by the same relative amount and they will stay in the same relationship to each other. To do this you iterate (loop) over all your tiles changing each tile's location by the *delta* amount, *(3, -2)*, i.e. you add *3* to the row and subtract *2* from the column.

Comment: I am bad speak english, sorry. example did not solve the problem. Yes, I want to move all the blocks.

Comment: @T.Cansiz - See addendum, HTH.